# How do I make an alert() that prints out the value of a variabile?

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm trying to make an alert, that prints the value of a variabile, here is my attempt.

```
var username = prompt("I'm LaunchBot, what's your name?");   
var print = alert() ;
```

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) and research before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alert a variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983288/alert-a-variable-value)

Comment: Per my answer to the above possible duplicate question:  alert("The variable named x1 has value:  " + x1);

Answer (score 2):

`alert()` is a function. It take a parameter between the parenthesis. So just insert your variable `username` between them:

```
var username = prompt("I'm LaunchBot, what's your name?");   
alert(username) ;
```

As suggested in the comment `alert()` doesn't return anything so do not add a variable assignment before.

Comment: Also, it doesn’t return anything, so `var print` is superfluous.

Comment: @Xufox nice catch i updated